# NiFi ExecuteSQL processor Charset Exceprion

Tags: java, db2, apache-nifi

I setup a workflow in Nifi that read from DB2 by `ExecuteSQL` processor and write somewhere. 
When I run some SQL commands that have **varchar** with special characters, I face the following error in `ExecuteSQL` processor.

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][1065][12306][XXX.XXX.XXX] Caught java.io.CharConversionException. See attached Throwable for details. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
>   [...]

I google this error and find that I can set the jcc configuration property `db2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3`. But I don't know where to set this config. I add this config in `JAVA_OPTIONS` system variable but not worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

db2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3 is an argument to the jvm that NiFi uses.

Try adding it in the bootstrap.conf  file of nifi, in the group of arguments that begin with prefix `java.arg.` like `java.arg.N=-Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3`  where N is the next available higher number than existing java.arg.n lines